# Php Looping debugging not desire result

Tags: php, html, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I need someone help me with my loop..

I want to create a rack that has 4 thumbnails images and every 4 images want to start a new one.. like this one i has with html :
[image]

I have my while loop to fetch all images from my database:

```
$query = "sp_supplier_info 0";      
$select_all_brochures = sqlsrv_query($con, $query);     
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($select_all_brochures)) {
   $brochures = json_decode($row['brochures'], true);
}
```

Then I create a for loop so I can fetch all data from that brochures array:

```
$a = count($brochures); 
for($i=0;$i<$a;$i++){  
    $bro_link = $brochures[$i]['href'];
    $bro_name = $brochures[$i]['name'];
    $thumb    = $brochures[$i]['thumbnail'];
    echo "<ul> //starts list
    <li class='popup'> //lists item I need 4
    <a href='{$bro_link}' target='_blank' title='{$bro_name}'><img alt='{$bro_name}' src='{$thumb}'></a>
    <span class='popuptext'>
    <div class='close'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></div>
    <div class='title ng-binding'>{$bro_name}</div>
    <button class='download' href='{$bro_link}'>Download</button>
    </span>
    </li>     //item                  
    </ul>
    //start rack
    <div class='rack hidden-xs'>
    <div class='top'>
    <div class='surface'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='bottom'></div>"; //end rack                 
}
```

But the result i get is that: [image]

So if I am not wrong I need 4 `<li class='popup'>` and after that I need to echo `</ul>
    //start rack
    <div class='rack hidden-xs'>
    <div class='top'>
    <div class='surface'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='bottom'></div>` that to create the rack, and start again from the first `<ul>` and that continue every 4 items.

I tried by creating an If statement `if($i % 4 == 0)` before `ul` and `<li>` but I got same result.

Can someone help?

Here is my full code:

```
    <div class="shelf"> 
    <?php
    $query = "sp_supplier_info 0";      
    $select_all_brochures = sqlsrv_query($con, $query);     
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($select_all_brochures)) {
        $brochures = json_decode($row['brochures'], true); 
        $a = count($brochures); 
        for($i=0;$i<$a;$i++){  
            $bro_link = $brochures[$i]['href'];
            $bro_name = $brochures[$i]['name'];
            $thumb    = $brochures[$i]['thumbnail'];
            echo "<ul>
            <li class='popup'>
            <a href='{$bro_link}' target='_blank' title='{$bro_name}'><img alt='{$bro_name}' src='{$thumb}'></a>
            <span class='popuptext'>
            <div class='close'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></div>
            <div class='title ng-binding'>{$bro_name}</div>
            <button class='download' href='{$bro_link}'>Download</button>
            </span>
            </li>                       
            </ul>
            <div class='rack hidden-xs'>
            <div class='top'>
            <div class='surface'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='bottom'></div>";                  
        }
    }     
    ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with the modulo operator.

Yo need to :

- Echo `<ul>` when `$i%4 == 0` (i.e. every 4 iterations, starting on the first one)
- Echo `<li>...</li>` on every iteration
- Echo `</ul><div....` when `$i%4 == 3` or `$i == $a-1`) (i.e. every 4 iteration, starting on the 4th one, and after the very last element)

Hereafter's the code :

```
<div class="shelf"> 
<?php
$query = "sp_supplier_info 0";      
$select_all_brochures = sqlsrv_query($con, $query);     
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($select_all_brochures)) {
    $brochures = json_decode($row['brochures'], true); 
    $a = count($brochures); 
    for($i=0;$i<$a;$i++){  
        $bro_link = $brochures[$i]['href'];
        $bro_name = $brochures[$i]['name'];
        $thumb    = $brochures[$i]['thumbnail'];
        if ($i%4 == 0)
            echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li class='popup'>
        <a href='{$bro_link}' target='_blank' title='{$bro_name}'><img alt='{$bro_name}' src='{$thumb}'></a>
        <span class='popuptext'>
        <div class='close'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></div>
        <div class='title ng-binding'>{$bro_name}</div>
        <button class='download' href='{$bro_link}'>Download</button>
        </span>
        </li>";
        if ($i%4 == 3 || $i == $a-1)
            echo "</ul>
            <div class='rack hidden-xs'>
            <div class='top'>
            <div class='surface'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='bottom'></div>";                  
    }
}     
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that exactly what i need. I forget to put the if statement to close my ul... cheers